# Fast question - Number of binary relations on a $3$-element set

Tags: combinatorics, relations, binary

I would like you to ask about counting set for $n = 3$.
So, this should be $2^9=512$, am I right?
In my set, there are:

- reflexive relation = $2^{n^2-n}=64$
- symmetric relation = $2^{(n^2+n)/2}=64$
- transitive relation = $171$
- antisymmetric relation = $2^n\cdot3^{(n^2-n)/2}=216$

Finally, when I add all this relations, I have $64+64+171+216=515$.
So, why is the different?
I would be grateful for help.

Comment: Beceause some relations have none of those properties and some have more than one.  It is as if you took a bowl of 20 fruits, counted 9 red fruits, 4 bumpy fruits, 3 underripe fruits, and 5 apples, and then asked "$9 + 4 + 3 + 5 = 21$, so why is this different?”

Comment: You're right. So, just do a simple subtraction operation: $512-357=155$ - that's the number of relations remaining. And it's done.

Comment: Bearing in mind some of the fruit be yellow smooth ripe bananas. (That is to say, none of the types of fruit listed).

Comment: It's really good comparison. :) $357$ is the sum of all 16 subsets, for 4 different relationships.

Comment: " So, just do a simple subtraction operation: 512−357=155"  Why?  " - that's the number of relations remaining. And it's done."  You weren't *asked* for the number remaining.  You were just asked for the number of relations.  And where did the number $357$ come from.  If that is the number of relations with one or more of the properties that is incorrect and you counted those that have more than one property multiple times.

Comment: If there were an smooth ripe red apple you would have counted that fruit two times (once for red and once for apples).  You were only supposed to count it once.  So " 357 is the sum of all 16 subsets, for 4 different relationships." is incorrect as you are counting many of the relations multiple times.

Comment: This is the result of a number that sums up all 16 subsets for this Venn diagram. (unfortunately, that's the real job - to count each subset separately). I am not sure about the counts of some subsets. Venn diagram shows 4 circles, where Z - reflexive relation, S - symmetric relation, A - antisymmetric relation and P - transitive relation. Can I ask you if these numbers are correctly spelled? Here's that diagram for n = 3: https://imgur.com/a/KlAHsyE

Answer (score 1):

You left out:

- None of the above.

And you double counted for all the relations that are one or more of the above types.

The total number is $2^{3^2} = 2^9$ and to get that by type,(if you *wanted* to get them by type... but there is *no* reason you should) you'd have to use the inclusion exclusion principal:

Total number is:  All the reflexive + all the symmetric + all the transitive + all the antisymmetric - all those that are both reflexive and symmetric - all the both reflexive and transitive - all the both reflexive and antisymmetric - all the both symmetric and transitive - all the both symmetric and antisymmetric - all the both transitive and antisymmetric + all that are reflexive symmetric and transitive + all that are reflexive symmetric and antisymmetric + all that are reflexive transitive and antisymmetric + all that are symmetric transitive and antisymmetric - those that are all four + those that are none of the four.

This would be very complicated to calculate and not all of the even *have* formulas for calculations.

But that will add to *ALL OF THEM*.

And the formula for all of them is $2^{n^2}$.

But that's why you didn't get the right answer:  You weren't counting any of the relations that were none of those types and you were double counting the ones that were.

In actuality you had utterly no *reason* to count them by type.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with special properties of relations such as reflexive, symmetric, and so on. Instead, your question is about the general concept of a binary relation.

A binary relation on a set $X$ is, by definition, a subset of $X \times X$. To put it another way, a binary relation on $X$ is an element of the power set $\mathcal P(X \times X)$.

If a set $X$ has $m$ elements then the set $Y = X \times X$ had $n=m^2$ elements.

And if a set $Y$ has $n$ elements then its power set $\mathcal P(Y)$ has $2^n$ elements.

So, the number of binary relations on a set with $m$ elements is equal to $2^{m^2}$.

In your case where $m=4$ you get
$$2^{4^2}=2^{16}=65536
$$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited that. I mean the case for $n = 3$.

Comment: It's not me. Maybe someone do that? I'll give You up-vote :) You're right.

Comment: @fleablood No good deed goes unpunished.